# count and sum function not working in left join

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the following 3 tables and i would like to know the correct sql for the expected result as below.
my sql here is not working;

```
select h.pid, 
       h.name, 
       sum(r.amount1) as total1, 
       sum(r.amount2) as total2, 
       count(g.pid) as times, 
       sum(g.take) as totaltaken
from history h 
left join rpt_revenue r on h.pid=r.pid 
left join guest g on g.pid=r.pid
group by h.pid, h.name;


history  
pid name  
1   peter  
2   may

rpt_revenue  
id  pid amount1 amount2  
1   1   10.00   11.00  
2   2   20.00   20.00  
3   1   2.00    2.00  
4   2   2.00    2.00  

guest  
gid pid id  take  
1   1   1   2  
2   1   3   2  
3   2   2   3  

expected result  
pid total1  total2  times   totaltaken  
1   12.00   13.00   2   4  
2   22.00   22.00   1   3
```

Comment: Did you try to group by revenue pid as well?

Comment: Yes, i did but no help...

Comment: Yeah it’s what I thought so you must do the aggregation in your join statements using sub queries in order to sum them at the top level

Comment: can you teach me by rewriting the sql?

Comment: I am on the phone on the train ahah I can try to find an example on the web, it would be easier

Comment: Here are some information https://learnsql.com/blog/introduction-using-aggregate-functions-joins/

Comment: many thanks for your assistance and no matter what of the result.

Comment: My pleasure tell me if you succeed

Comment: My pleasure :) I will write a response later

Answer (score 0):

So to be able to use aggregate function over join, you should first aggregate your data in a join subquery and then aggregate all of them at the top level

[here](https://learnsql.com/blog/introduction-using-aggregate-functions-joins/) some examples of aggregation